# Auth Provider with a Google account: redirect the user after they log in

Tags: single-sign-on, experience-cloud, auth-provider

I have setup SSO for an experience cloud site, I selected Google for the SSO and did not specify the authentication URLs and consumer key/secret.

The SSO works fine, what I want to do is redirect the user after they log in through the google SSO, I am following these steps:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_provider_addl_params_redirect.htm&type=5

I should add `?startURL=<page_name>` to my SSO Initialization URL, I am not able to edit them when I go to `Setup -> Auth. Providers > provider (Google Login) -> Edit`

I tried adding it to the URL suffix : `Google_Login?startURL=onboarding`
But getting an error that the URL suffix field can only contain alphanumeric characters.

Does anyone know where I can add the redirection parameters?

See below the image of my configuration

- Single Sign-On Initialization URL https://sdodemo-main-166ceb6-172-17ac9e9435a.force.com/B2BLightning/services/auth/sso/Google_Login
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for my use case, in my front-end code I simply took the initialisation URL and added:  `?startURL=/s/onboarding` when the user clicks on the sign in to google button.

So I did not had to change anything in the actual auth provider configuration itself, I don't think it is intended to change it there which I was trying to do.